# MenuItem material-ui - can not change the height

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Please help.

Any of props which are passed to MenuItem can not help me to change the height of that element.

```
 <MenuItem
       innerDivStyle={{height: "20px"}}
       value={itemValue}
       primaryText={(multiple && withCheckboxes) ? '' : itemNode}
       key={index}
       style={{height: "20px"}}
 >
     here is checkbox 
 </MenuItem>
```

Anyone knows how to change that? I used React dev tools and inspection in Chrome and couldn't fix it even there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: @supra28 version: 0.20.1

Comment: You are missing a '}' in your innerDivStyle

Comment: doesn't matter mistake when I was copying cuz styles are in another place ;)